# Regex in youtube-dl arguments

Tags: regex, command-line-arguments, youtube-dl

I want to extract two paths from the youtube-dl arguments, the output template and ffmpeg location

```
-o (.*%\(ext\)s).* --ffmpeg-location (.*)
```

With the regex above I am able to capture both the output template and the ffmpeg location from the expression below

```
-o D:/Deskttop/test//%(title)s.%(ext)s -i -f (best)[height=1080]/best --recode-video mp4 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MMuUFjxLQJU --no-playlist --encoding utf-8 --ffmpeg-location D:/Deskttop/test/
```

The problem is that sometimes the ffmpeg location is not provided, like this:

```
-o D:/Deskttop/test//%(title)s.%(ext)s -i -f (best)[height=1080]/best --recode-video mp4 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MMuUFjxLQJU --no-playlist --encoding utf-8
```

I want to able to capture the output template even when ffmpeg location is not present in the expression using only one regular expression.

I am testing this [here](https://regex101.com/r/aBmSx7/1).

Comment: Try if this pattern `-o (.*%\(ext\)s).* (?:(?:--ffmpeg-location )?(.*))?` works with your data.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio thanks, the regex you gave me doesn't work 100%, ideally it should not capture a second match if ffmpeg-location is not provided. As you can see here https://regex101.com/r/4cUn3J/1. But your regex will be sufficient for the current need. I will try to work on it and try to achieve the ideal solution. If you can do it, you should post it as an answer so I can mark the correct answer

Comment: Is [that](https://regex101.com/r/Q93WRP/1) what you want,

Comment: @Toto yes, perfect. Thank you. Post it as an answer to mark as the accepted one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I make my comment an answer.

Use this regex, it works for both cases:

```
-o (.*%\(ext\)s).+?(?:--ffmpeg-location (.+?))?$
```

[Demo & Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/Q93WRP/1)

Comment: +1 very succinct compared to what I would have written :)

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio: Thanks.